# Time between quarter end/fiscal year end till earnings report

Tags: corporate-earnings

with a public company that is expected to report earnings at a regular interval, how long after a reporting period do earnings usually get announced/released?

Real world example would be Fiscal Year ending at "end of February" as stated in an 8-K, no earnings date announced or pattern of releasing earnings.

how many days later would a complaint public company that will be expected to report quarterly earnings release their report? I am assuming there is a standard, or industry best practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are regulatory deadlines in the US set by SEC. You can read about it [here](http://www.sec.gov/rules/final/33-8128.htm).

> The annual report deadline will remain 90 days for year one and
>   change from 90 days to 75 days for year two and from 75 days to 60
>   days for year three and thereafter. The quarterly report deadline will
>   remain 45 days for year one and change from 45 days to 40 days for
>   year two and from 40 days to 35 days for year three and thereafter.

Comment: Note to others: the *"year one"*, *"year two"*, etc. in the quote are with respect to a phase-in period for a rule-change that happened a while ago; the latter values (60 days for annual, 35 days for quarterly) would now be in effect.  See http://www.sec.gov/rules/final/33-8128.htm#IC1

Comment: including @ChrisW.Rea do particular exchanges have tighter deadlines to your knowledge?

Comment: Tigher? Not that I'm aware of. But looser, yes. I know that in Canada, for instance, the Toronto Stock Exchange (TSX) has 90 days for annual, 45 days for quarterly. Of course, I expect those larger companies cross-listed on a U.S. exchange would be subject to the tighter SEC rules.

Comment: @CQM that's the longest allowed period, but many times companies perform the earnings' calls way before the actual filing deadline. Last quarter, my company did it 25 days after the quarter end, 10 days before the deadline.